# Setting number value in JavaScript via Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app is using Razor in the views. I am putting values in the ViewBag to use in my view. I have a property on the ViewBag called 'ItemId'. That value may be assigned an int value. Or, it may not be set at all. If it is set, I want to assign it to a value in JavaScript. If it is not set, I want to use -1.

Currently, I am trying the following:

```
var id= @((String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ItemId)) ? ViewBag.ItemId : "-1");
```

Unfortunately, when this gets run, my JavaScript looks like this:

```
var id = ;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a `!`: you are using that ItemId *when* it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following jQuery code:

```
@var id;  // declare id as global first

@if(ViewBag.ItemId!=null)
{
    id = ViewBag.ItemId;
}
else
{
 id=-1;
}

var itemID ="@id";  //then save razor id in javascript var itemID
itemID = parseInt(itemID) // for any further clearance
```

hope this helps